# The server has returned this error message:Duplicate column name 'NULL' MySQL Error

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to restore a backup from another server to a new one but I got this error:

Error while executing this query:

```sql
CREATE algorithm=undefined definer=root@localhost sql security definer VIEW resellers ASSELECT resellers1.id AS id,
       ( 
              SELECT clienttypes.id_client_type AS id_client_type 
              FROM   clienttypes 
              WHERE  ( 
                            clienttypes.id_client_type = 64)) AS client_type, 
       resellers1.idreseller                                  AS idReseller, 
       resellers1.login                                       AS login, 
       resellers1.password                                    AS password, 
       resellers1.type                                        AS type, 
       resellers1.id_tariff                                   AS id_tariff, 
       resellers1.callslimit                                  AS callsLimit, 
       resellers1.clientslimit                                AS clientsLimit, 
       resellers1.tech_prefix                                 AS tech_prefix, 
       resellers1.identifier                                  AS identifier, 
       resellers1.fullname                                    AS Fullname, 
       resellers1.address                                     AS Address, 
       resellers1.city                                        AS City, 
       resellers1.zipcode                                     AS ZipCode, 
       resellers1.country                                     AS Country, 
       resellers1.phone                                       AS Phone, 
       resellers1.email                                       AS Email, 
       resellers1.maxclients                                  AS MaxClients, 
       resellers1.template_id                                 AS template_id, 
       resellers1.taxid                                       AS TaxID, 
       resellers1.type2                                       AS type2, 
       resellers1.language                                    AS language 
FROM   resellers1 
WHERE  ( 
              NOT( 
                     EXISTS 
                     ( 
                            SELECT clientsshared.id_reseller AS id_reseller 
                            FROM   clientsshared 
                            WHERE  (( 
                                                 clientsshared.id_tariff = -(2)) 
                                   AND    ( 
                                                 resellers1.login = clientsshared.login) 
                                   AND    ( 
                                                 resellers1.password = clientsshared.password)))))
UNION ALL 
SELECT resellers2.id AS id, 
       ( 
              SELECT clienttypes.id_client_type AS id_client_type 
              FROM   clienttypes 
              WHERE  ( 
                            clienttypes.id_client_type = 65)) AS client_type, 
       resellers2.idreseller                                  AS idReseller, 
       resellers2.login                                       AS login, 
       resellers2.password                                    AS password, 
       resellers2.type                                        AS type, 
       resellers2.id_tariff                                   AS id_tariff, 
       resellers2.callslimit                                  AS callsLimit, 
       resellers2.clientslimit                                AS clientsLimit, 
       resellers2.tech_prefix                                 AS tech_prefix, 
       resellers2.identifier                                  AS identifier, 
       resellers2.fullname                                    AS Fullname, 
       resellers2.address                                     AS Address, 
       resellers2.city                                        AS City, 
       resellers2.zipcode                                     AS ZipCode, 
       resellers2.country                                     AS Country, 
       resellers2.phone                                       AS Phone, 
       resellers2.email                                       AS Email, 
       NULL                                                   AS NULL, 
       resellers2.template_id                                 AS template_id, 
       resellers2.taxid                                       AS TaxID, 
       resellers2.type2                                       AS type2, 
       resellers2.language                                    AS language 
FROM   resellers2 
UNION ALL 
SELECT resellers3.id AS id, 
       ( 
              SELECT clienttypes.id_client_type AS id_client_type 
              FROM   clienttypes 
              WHERE  ( 
                            clienttypes.id_client_type = 66)) AS client_type, 
       NULL                                                   AS NULL, 
       resellers3.login                                       AS login, 
       resellers3.password                                    AS password, 
       resellers3.type                                        AS type, 
       resellers3.id_tariff                                   AS id_tariff, 
       resellers3.callslimit                                  AS callsLimit, 
       resellers3.clientslimit                                AS clientsLimit, 
       resellers3.tech_prefix                                 AS tech_prefix, 
       resellers3.identifier                                  AS identifier, 
       resellers3.fullname                                    AS Fullname, 
       resellers3.address                                     AS Address, 
       resellers3.city                                        AS City, 
       resellers3.zipcode                                     AS ZipCode, 
       resellers3.country                                     AS Country, 
       resellers3.phone                                       AS Phone, 
       resellers3.email                                       AS Email, 
       NULL                                                   AS NULL, 
       NULL                                                   AS NULL, 
       resellers3.taxid                                       AS TaxID, 
       resellers3.type2                                       AS type2, 
       resellers3.language                                    AS language 
FROM   resellers3;
```

The server has returned this error message:

> Duplicate column name 'NULL'
>   MySQL Error.

Any thoughts what the problem is and how to fix it?

Comment: Look towards the end you have `NULL as NULL, NULL as NULL` being duplicate column names. I also recommend reading some guidelines on posting questions with proper formatting to make it easier to debug for people.

Answer (score 0):

Three times in your SQL statement you have the words `NULL AS NULL`, which isn't correct.

```
where (clienttypes.id_client_type = 66)) AS client_type,NULL AS NULL,resellers3.login AS login

Email AS Email,NULL AS NULL,NULL AS NULL,resellers3.TaxID AS TaxID
```

There are a couple of problems. NULL isn't likely to be a column name and you can't define more than one column with the same alias.